# How to format Credit card text edit widget?

Tags: qt

I am trying to make a custom format for my credit card widget. The first 4 numbers should be followed by a dash `'-'`, then after 3 numbers, another dash and then 2 more numbers.

Example: `1234-678-52`.

How can I custom format a text edit so that it has `'-'` already present and follows the format described above?

The built-in date widget has something similar: having `'/'` as a delimiter.

Comment: Pretty sure the date widget uses a line edit and not a text-edit...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using QLineEdit the option is to use the [inputMask](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop) property:

```cpp
your_qlineedit->setInputMask("999-9999-99");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use three input fields. Place them in one line, draw the '-' in between and add the input masks and some logic.

- Input masks: 999, 9999, 99
- Logic 1: Go to next input field as soon the input is accepted
- Logic 2: Go to previous field as soon all characters are deleted (optional)

The user should now be able to type in the whole number without pressing TAB or '-'.